# Auto-Generate Quiz Questions & Answers for JavaScript App: Do I Need a Database?

Tags: javascript, security, web-applications

For a small, learning the language (JavaScript) better project, I'd like to create a simple quiz web app. I have two questions:

1. If my questions and answers will always be the same and I'm creating a quiz app that only uses multiple choice questions (I assume I'll use radio buttons for selectors), do I need a database? Or can I simply code all my questions and answers into an array of objects inside say a main.js file?

Each object would have a question, four option answers, and the correct answer. Then it's a simple if statement to compare the selection against the correct answer.

I ask this predominately because I'm afraid there'd be a security issue by not using a database, though I can't figure out why since users wouldn't submit anything.

2. Taking it a step further: To make it more dynamic, instead of writing out every single question and answer, could I dynamically generate questions and potential answers using objects?

Say I have a list of soccer objects which are teams. Inside each team object, I list positions and a player names. Some positions have multiple players. Then I have a separate object filled with questions.

Could I set a random number on the Questions object to randomly generate a question then have some logic that knows when that question is generated, only these certain key value pairings from my objects can fit as answers?

E.g. if the question is, "Which one of these is a Manchester United defender?" It would pull a random one Manchester United defender and randomly fill up the remaining three options with defenders from other teams.

Every time I try to write it out logically, I get muddled so I think I'm approaching this poorly.

Thanks and sorry for the rookie questions!

Answer (score 0):

If your questions and answers will always be the same than you can surely skip the data base and use Questions object within Array e.g.,

```
var myQuestions= [{
//your question-answer details goes here - key value pair
}];
```

and every time a new user come to take test use random method (built in JS Method) for getting question from your Question array.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding the security issue, what do you mean by 'users wouldn't submit anything' ?? They will submit the answers, right?? Or do you mean user's answer won't be stored, instead the feedback on answer will be shown in client-side itself? Also, if you store multiple choice options with one flagged as answer in js file, the user can inspect the contents of the js file from browser & get to know the answers.

Comment: I meant they wouldn't type their own answers. It'd just be sending information via a radio button, I suppose.

Is there any way to prevent them from inspecting the JS file without hosting it on a database? It's not that big of a deal, because the quiz is just for fun. But all the same. Thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

1. I am in the assumption of your security issue meant the users are able to know the answer through reading your script. Anything that is 'client sided' will never be secure. Eg: storing your answers in a JS script and load it in client's browser.
2. Making objects such as "teams" would require you to implement intelligence in your quiz app in order for it to know which question would co-relate with which object, and to differentiate between the right answer and wrong answer. This is not impossible, but not trivial. To avoid a lot of complexities, you can make it as such:

   ```
   /* Javascript array to store object sets of question, right answers, and wrong answers */
   var quizObj = [{ 
           "question": "Which of the following is MU's defender?",
           "right": ["Marcos Rojo", "Luke Shaw", "Tyler Blacket"],
           "wrong": ["Vincent Kompany", "Dejen Lovren", "Javi Manquillo", "Mathieu Debuchy", "Calum Chambers"]
   }];

   /* Function to get a random index in an array */
   function getRandomIndex(array) { return Math.floor(Math.random()*array.length); }

   /* Please apply your proper looping here */
   var current = quizObj[0];

   /* To get a random right answer: */
   var rightAnswer = current.right[getRandomIndex(current.right)];

   /* To get wrong answers which is unique: */
   var tempWrong = current.wrong.slice(); // Clone the array because splice will change the original array (and that is why we can make the output unique)

   /* Get the random answer and remove it from the temporary array */
   var wrongAnswer1 = tempWrong.splice(getRandomIndex(tempWrong), 1)[0]; 
   var wrongAnswer2 = tempWrong.splice(getRandomIndex(tempWrong), 1)[0]; 
   var wrongAnswer3 = tempWrong.splice(getRandomIndex(tempWrong), 1)[0];
   ```

Comment: Here is a fiddle to show you random selection of right and wrong answers: http://jsfiddle.net/6w98wr8s/

Comment: Wow, fantastic answer thank you!

My security issue was just concerned that someone could permanently alter the JS file. But I couldn't think of a reasonable way they would. I just wanted to confirm.

I really appreciate you putting that together. I think you're right: That's going to be far too complicated. I'll just have to type out every bloody question. Here comes hours of work! Thanks!!

Comment: Nope they would never be able to modify your JS files without getting write access to your filesystem (like FTP). You're welcome :)